# Insertar registro a otra con triggers

Tags: sql, postgresql

tengo una consulta y no sé si puede hacer.
Tengo una tabla de alumnos donde se registran las notas de los alumnos. Las notas van de 0 al 20, necesitando el 10.5 para aprobar.
La tabla tiene las columnas de ID, nombre, nota y estado (Aprobado o Desaprobado).
Lo que busco es cuando la columna Estado se actualice a Desaprobado, este registro pase a otra tabla de nombre AlumnosDesaprobados.
Lo que hice hasta ahora es crear una función y un trigger que cada vez que se actualiza la tabla alumnos inserta los nuevos registros a AlumnosDesaprobados, pero no se cómo añadir la condición de que solo lo haga cuando se actualice la columna Estado a Desaprobado.
Soy novato

```
create function sp_test() returns Trigger
as
$$
begin
insert into "alumnosdesaprobados" values (new.*);
return new;
end
$$
Language plpgsql;
create trigger TR_update after update on alumnos
for each row
execute procedure SP_Test();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes añadir la condición que verifique si el nuevo registro se diferencia del antiguo en la columna de estado
Dentro de tu función trigger
Cómo por ejemplo:

```
create function sp_test() returns Trigger
as
$$
begin
IF new.estado<> old.estado THEN
  insert into "alumnosdesaprobados" values (new.*);
End IF;

return new;
end
$$
Language plpgsql;
create trigger TR_update after update on alumnos
for each row
execute procedure SP_Test();
```

O también puedes escribir el trigger para que se dispare solo cuando se modifique la columna que requieres

```
create trigger TR_update after update
of estado
on alumnos
for each row
execute procedure SP_Test();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono a la perfección.